# isp - how is it impossible to connect internet except homepage?

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, proxy

one of ISP in my country allows free access to their website, but we have to buy data package to access the other internet. 
My question is: how does this works( accessing one website but not others)? Is there a possibility to bypass this limitation without having to buy data package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ISP knows the IP address of their website so won't impose any traffic policing on requests going to that particular IP address. We cannot help you circumvent your ISP's terms of service.